# How to further vectorize this function?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I have the following mathematical formula 
[image]

Which implemented via python in the following way

```
import numpy as np
import math

def f(W, V, mu, sigma, q, w):
    A = np.tile(1 + mu + math.sqrt(2)*sigma*q, (np.size(W), 1))
    _W = (A.T * W).T
    _W = w * V(np.ravel(_W)).reshape(np.size(W), len(q))
    return np.sum(_W, axis=1)
```

The main input of the function is `W`. The parameters `q` and `w` are always the same. For `W` the function is vectorized as the following example shows:

```
f(np.asarray([100, 10320, 103]), np.log, 0.03, 0.1, np.polynomial.hermite.hermgauss(10)[0], np.polynomial.hermite.hermgauss(10)[1])
Out: array([ 8.20636769, 16.42464925,  8.2587593 ])
```

As you see `mu` and `sigma` are fixed. I'm wondering if can vectorize it further, i.e. `mu` and `sigma` would be arrays of the same length. Currently, I would do:

```
mu = [0.03, 0.05, 0.1]
sigma = [0.1, 0.12, 0.20]
[f(np.asarray([100, 10320, 103]), np.log, mu[i], sigma[i], np.polynomial.hermite.hermgauss(10)[0], np.polynomial.hermite.hermgauss(10)[1]) for i in range(0, len(mu))]

Out: 
[array([ 8.20636769, 16.42464925,  8.2587593 ]),
 array([ 8.23711733, 16.4553989 ,  8.28950895]),
 array([ 8.30043707, 16.51871863,  8.35282868])]
```

In my real example the lists are much larger and I do a multiprocessing for the different `mu` and `sigma`. However, since I'm doing this many times I was wondering if I could do it more efficiently in a vectorized form for `mu`and `sigma` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The only use of `mu` and `sigma` is in the construction of `A`:

```
1 + mu[0] + math.sqrt(2)*sigma[0]*q
```

To use arrays for `mu` and `sigma` rather than scalars, you can construct all the `A`s at once:

```
1 + mu + math.sqrt(2)*sigma*q[:,np.newaxis]
```

This gives you an array with shape `(10, 3)`; the second dimension matches `len(mu)` and `len(sigma)` because `newaxis` tells NumPy that you want to expand the shape in that dimension to match the other arrays.

You can continue from there: construct the full set of `A`s by an incantation of `tile`, then do the multiplications all at once (perhaps using `einsum`, and so on.  This leaves much as an exercise for the reader, but if you take it one step at a time I think you can make it.

Comment: thx for your answer. I'm a bit struggeling with the einsum. Could you maybe elaborate a bit more on that part?

Comment: @math: einsum is a bit complex and you may not even need it.  I'd try to do it using more basic tools first, unless you want to start with a tutorial on einsum and try to learn about that (but be warned: it is not for everyone!).